# Set a date field by rules

Tags: rules, datetime

I have a problem that has been discussed a lot, but I still fail at dealing with it.
I need to *get* and *set* the the value of the field by Rules. I put my conditions allright, then I define "Set a data value" as a desired action. At this point, the direct input is disabled, I can only point to another field (as far as I can understand): "switch to direct input mode" is disabled (does not appear, in fact).
Now,I've seen a number of discussions related to the issue. It seems to be related to the way the *Date* module handles things.

The issue seems widely discussed: 
Date module:
https://drupal.org/node/1431952 (Date field will only set in Rules if it already has a value)
https://drupal.org/node/1153766 (provide a property setter callback)
Rules Module:
https://drupal.org/node/1611666 (Action "Set a data value" is not working for   date field)

There are also more general guides
[Drupal 7, Rules, Convert text to date and set a date field](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/51786/drupal-7-rules-convert-text-to-date-and-set-a-date-field) (as setting the date supposedly works for timestamps)

While most of the problems seem solved, I can't achieve the simple (I assumed)  goal I want to get to. Can anybody explain how to connect the pieces of information and make it work as intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The patch from 
https://drupal.org/comment/8195767#comment-8195767 
seems to solve the problem.